# Cucumber's "The step is not defined" for using steps definitions from .jar library

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

I've installed .jar with steps definitions with:
`mvn install:install-file`, set `glue = {"com.company.test"}` and can go to step definition (Ctrl+LMB) from .feature, and also run test from here.

But for running test from Runner I receive information that steps are undefined.

Comment: Are u able to run the feature file successfully through a runner etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runner executed properly, when I wrote names of packages without mentioning that they exist in external jar.